# RecyclerView cannot be applied to FlexboxLayoutManager

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm tryng to use `FlexboxLayoutManager`, I followed the tutorial, but I'm getting this problem:

**setLayoutManager (android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.LayoutManager)
in RecyclerView cannot be applied to (com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayoutManager)**

Here is my code :

```
  FlexboxLayoutManager layoutManager = new FlexboxLayoutManager(FreightResultActivity.this);
  layoutManager.setFlexDirection(FlexDirection.COLUMN);
  layoutManager.setJustifyContent(JustifyContent.FLEX_END);
  recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Comment: Nothing in that code looks wrong. FlexboxLayoutManager is a subclass of RecyclerView.LayoutManager, so the error is bogus. I'd try a gradle sync and clean build and see if that clears things up.

Comment: Android Studio sometimes says things like this after a build (or before any builds at all). For instance, I've had it say that my cast of `findViewById()` to a Button was wrong because it was expecting `View` and `Button` isn't a View, which it is. Usually building again makes it go away.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using the latest version of Flexbox (1.1.0) it uses AndroidX so the `FlexboxLayoutManager` actually extends `androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.LayoutManager`, that can cause this exception. Try migrating to androidx; using `androidx.recyclerview:RecyclerView:1.0.0` as the recyclerview dependency should fix your problem.
Android Studio has "Migrate to AndroidX" feature under "Refactor" you can use that to do the migration.

Answer (score 4):

The versions of Flexbox above and including **1.1.0** support only to be used with **AndroidX**, so you have two solutions:

1. Migrate your project to AndroidX.

or

2. Use the **1.0.0** version of flexbox, i.e., replace your current implementation in build.gradle to the following.

`implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:1.0.0'`

I suggest you use the 2nd solution.

Thanks, I guess this helps.

Comment: updated gradle dependency - implementation 'com.google.android.flexbox:flexbox:3.0.0'

Answer (score 2):

use library version 1.0.0(implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:1.0.0') if you haven't migrated to AndroidX.
this resolve the provlem

Answer (score 1):

Note that starting from 1.1.0, the library(implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:1.1.0') is expected to use with AndroidX. Please migrate to AndroidX if you use 1.1.0 or above.

**Please use library version 1.0.0(implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:1.0.0') if you haven't migrated to AndroidX.**